# Is this an error-handling anti-pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A colleague recently told me this is an anti-pattern (`record` is an `ActiveRecord`):

```
  begin
    record.save!
    do_something_else
  rescue => e
    puts "Unable to save"
  end
```

...and I should do this instead:

```
  if record.save
    do_something_else
  else
    puts "Unable to save"
  end
```

His argument is that I'm using an exception for flow control (which I agree is bad) but I believe this is a typical error-handling pattern.

Thoughts?

Comment: Don't use exceptions for control flow.  It's more expensive to raise exceptions than it is to do if checks.

Comment: Related/dupe: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/54997

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an antipattern, because there are better ways to check the validity of a record than running `save!` (which raises an error if it's not valid).

This is probably what your colleague was getting at:

```
  if record.save
    do_something_else
  else
    puts record.errors.full_messages
  end
```

You see, there is just no benefit here of using the error as control flow because there are less roundabout ways to do it.

You can also run the validations independently of the save attempt. The `errors.full_messages` array (of strings) is populated when `record.valid?` gets called. `record.save` calls `record.valid?` internally.

```
if record.valid?
  record.save # or save!; by this point you can assume the record is valid
else
  puts record.errors.full_messages
end
```

Comment: In your second case `save(false)` or now `save(validate: false)` would be better since `valid?` has already validated the record and `save` will do so again unnecessarily.